# How to set Value of <input> element that doesn't have a .value option?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an  element ("moduleId") that I am inputting 5 numbers into. Although it is impractical, I attempted to SendKeys the numbers individually but nothing happened. Before that, I attempted to set the value of the element itself, but that errored as there appears to be no value "variable" if you will on the element. How do I set the "moduleId" value?

[image]

---

Here's what I've tried:

```
Set HTMLdoc = .Document
    Set inputColl = HTMLdoc.querySelector("div.sturdy input[name='moduleId']")
    inputColl.Value = "46432"
```

This gave me an "Object variable or With block variable not set" error.

I've also tried merely SendKey-ing it, but that hasn't worked either.

```
Application.SendKeys "{4}"
Application.SendKeys "{6}"
Application.SendKeys "{4}"
Application.SendKeys "{3}"
Application.SendKeys "{2}"
```

For some reason, this does not appear to accept SendKeys even when manually focused using breakpoints.

---

**SOLUTION**

Turns out my .Document was not refreshing as the site I was using had no .Busy state, hence I was unable to use my standard "wait" function. I added a loop to wait until the link changed to the proper link and then continued.

```
Do Until .LocationURL = "NA"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
Loop
    
Set HTMLdoc = .Document
Set inputField = HTMLdoc.getElementById("moduleId")
inputField.Value = "46432"
```

Comment: Garret wrote: *"Before that, I attempted to set the value of the element itself, but that errored as there appears to be no value "variable" if you will on the element"*
What is the error and please show us the VBA code. Please no more screendumps!

Comment: Even if there's no "value" attribute in the source HTML, you can still set the `Value`.  As suggested already, please show the code you tried and describe what happened when you ran it.

Comment: Apologies, added some of the code I have attempted, hopefully it makes sense